# Trying to make a procedural environment in netlogo

Tags: netlogo

So this simple block of code will create clusters of black patches in the environment.

I would like to know how to procedurally paint and repaint them in the environment.
The effect I'm going for is periodically disappearing patches and reappearing in a random location.

```
 ask patches in-radius random 3.5 
  [
    set pcolor black 
  ]
```

I don't know how I would apply pseudo code logic like:

```
while(true)
{
  if(ticks % 100)//If ticks are a multiple of hundred
    {
     clear black patches
     paint clusters of patches
    }else{ do nothing}
}.
```

-in netlogo syntax.

Any help is very much appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ask patches with [pcolor = black and <near a certain point>] [...]`

But ... if I am not misunderstanding the nature of your question, I think you need to work through at least the beginning of a tutorial on NetLogo first, or take a look at some of the examples in the Models Library that's available on the File menu.  I'm not going to rewrite the tutorial here.  For example, you don't need a `while` loop, given what you've said so far.  You need to use a `run` procedure.  That's the sort of basic idea you should learn before doing anything else.  Since you already have some understanding of programming, it won't take long.